# Aggregate exception error on SignalR

Tags: c#, signalr

I am creating a separate TestServer and TestClient separately using SignalR. For some reason I get this error:

```
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait()
   at TestClient.Program.Main(String[] args) in h:\SignalR\TestClient\TestClient\Program.cs:line 15
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

But if I create the project in one solution and run it, I don't get any problems.

This is my code for the TestServer on TestHub

```
[HubName("TestHub")]
    class TestHub : Hub
    {
        public void DetermineLength(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            var newMessage = string.Format(@"{0} has a length of: {1}", message, message.Length);
            Clients.All.ReceiveLength(newMessage);
        }
    }
```

My code for the TestServer on Main

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
            using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Server running at {0}",url));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

This is the code on the Client on Main

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IHubProxy _hub;
            var url = @"http://localhost:8080/";
            var connection = new HubConnection(url);
            _hub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");
            connection.Start().Wait(); // *this is where I get the error

            string line = null;
            while ((line = System.Console.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                _hub.Invoke("DetermineLength", line).Wait();
            }
            _hub.On("ReceiveLegth", x => Console.WriteLine(x));
        }
    }
```

Can you show me the right way to do it? Thanks.

Comment: What does the aggregate exception say? There's one or more exceptions encapsulated in the `AggregateException` (hence the name).

Comment: It is in the first part of the post.

Comment: You've just given us the stack trace, not the actual content of the exception(s)

Comment: How do you run your server and the client when they are in the same solution. If you client is marked as start application you might be starting the client but not the server so there is no server the client is trying to connect to.

Comment: InnerException: {"StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  Date: Tue, 25 Apr 2017 22:26:10 GMT\r\n  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0\r\n  Content-Length: 0\r\n}"}

Comment: If they are on the same solution, when I click run, the 2 starts at the same time. But when it is in separate solutions, I run the server first followed by the client